# Is it possible to apply a particular bootstrap class only for a particular devices and not for other's.?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, css

for example, I applied an input group class and I want it to be applied only when the site is accessed through small devices but if the site is accessed using large devices I don't want that class to be applied. I could have used visible-xs, hidden-xs classes but I don't want to do that as I don't want to change the markup for small and large devices.

Answer (score 0):

use jquery for this purpose.

```
if($(window).width() >= 1024){
// call the element by id and add your class
}
```

You can use the below code as reference.

```
if($(window).width() >= 1024){
  $('#mydiv').addClass('col-lg-4');
}


<div id="mydiv">
  </div>
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Nothing will happen after a resize with those 2 snippets, that says nothing about classes involved in styling input groups in Bootstrap and imho `.matchMedia()` would be a better candidate if OP doesn't have to support IE8 and 9 (even in that case, one can assume that if it isn't supported then it isn't a mobile)

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Sass and BS v4 (or LESS and v3.x), you could create your own class like `.xs-input-group` and apply to it a copy-pasted-modified version of [input-group.scss](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/blob/v4-dev/scss/_input-group.scss) ([v3 LESS version is in master](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/blob/master/less/input-groups.less))

You'll also have to rename `.input-group-addon` and `.input-group-btn` both in your HTML and preprocessor code because they're styled *as is*, not with a safeguard like `.input-group .input-group-something {}` so even if no parent has the `.input-group` class, they'd still be somewhat styled by BS...

It's better to either prefix or remove `.input-group-lg` and `.*-sm`, depends if you intend to use this sizing feature one day or not.